# If condition in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I've searched through google and here but didn't find an answer to my question.

I'm trying to use IF in a query (not stored procedure) in that way:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE) THEN
DO SOMETHING
END IF;
```

I've tryed in MySql Workbench and didn't work (Syntax error).

Anybody knows if it's possible to use IF in that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What `SOMETHING` do you wish to `DO` ?

Comment: SOMETHING in that case in an INSERT .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is SOMETHING

If it is an UPDATE, DELETE or SELECT, you can specify the conditions in the where clause.

```
WHERE IF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE) > 0, 1, 2) = 1
```

For other statements (INSERT, CREATE, etc.) i don't think this is possible.

Comment: I need to do an insert but before that I need to check if already exists a row with these values.

Comment: @Valerio: So, if a record already exists with `COLUMN=VALUE` you don't want the `INSERT` to be performed?  Why not define a `UNIQUE` index over `COLUMN`, which will enforce such a constraint for you?

Comment: for inserts, see the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. It is not exactly the same, but maybe it is what you are looking for

Comment: @eggyal: In my case I need to check 4 column for duplicate value. I'll try in that way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you say that "SOMETHING" is an `INSERT` operation. You can then, instead of:

```
INSERT INTO tableName
  (colA, colB, ...)
VALUES
  (a, b, ...) ;
```

use:

```
INSERT INTO tableName
  (colA, colB, ...)
SELECT
  a, b, ... 
FROM 
  dual
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE) ;
```

Comment: Didn't know this syntax :( . I'm gonna try. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I've tryed this syntax and I need to insert only if record doesn't alredy exists so after a couple of test I've seen that the correct syntax for me is : INSERT INTO tableName
  (colA, colB, ...)
SELECT
  a, b, ... 
FROM 
  dual
WHERE
  **NOT** EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE);

Comment: Thanks ! I've some problem with writing comments ;)